# Spartacus: how to close the hamburger menu on link click

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Is there a way to close the mobile hamburger menu when you click on a menu link?  We have a menu link that launches a modal window, but the menu is still showing behind it when I close the modal.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the hamburger menu is kept in HamburgerMenuService. You  can inject this service in your modal for example you can call the toggle(false) method in this component's onInit hook.

This way when the modal initializes the menu will close.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers.  This is how I achieved the task:

1. Inject the `HamburgerMenuService` into the component:

`import { HamburgerMenuService } from ‘@spartacus/storefront’;`

2. Add my constructor:

`constructor(private hamburger: HamburgerMenuService) {}`

3. Access the toggle method in my modal function:

`this.hamburger.toggle(true); // force close`